# Python 3.8 Function Return Output Issue

Tags: python-3.x

I have put the following function together in Python 3.8 using Pycharm.

```
def make_album(artist_name, album_title):
    album_details = {'artist': artist_name, 'title': album_title}
    return album_details


while True:
    print("\nEnter the name of your favourite album & artist.")
    print("Or press 'q' to quit.")
    artist = input("Favourite Artist: ")
    if artist == 'q':
        break
    title = input("Favourite Album: ")
    if artist == 'q':
        break

full_details = make_album(artist, title)
print(full_details)
```

When I run the program and enter 'q' to quit, the output is:

```
Enter the name of your favourite album & artist.
Or press 'q' to quit.
Favourite Artist: band
Favourite Album: album

Enter the name of your favourite album & artist.
Or press 'q' to quit.
Favourite Artist: q
{'artist': 'q', 'title': 'album'}
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What do you expect as output?

Comment: You test `artist` twice. Anyway, you will always end up with a `'q'` in one of the categories.

Answer (score 0):

I's an indentation problem. And also you need to use `else`.

```py
def make_album(artist_name, album_title):
    album_details = {'artist': artist_name, 'title': album_title}
    return album_details


while True:
    print("\nEnter the name of your favourite album & artist.")
    print("Or press 'q' to quit.")
    artist = input("Favourite Artist: ")
    if artist == 'q':
        break
    else:
        title = input("Favourite Album: ")
    full_details = make_album(artist, title)
    print(full_details)
```

You don't need to test `artist` twice. Once if you are checking it for `'q'` then break it, else continue your process.